# cursor update in with arcpy to fill in values

Tags: python, arcpy

I have some code from my instructor but when I run it as a script in modeler it produces an error.
Here is a piece of the code, the rest repeats but with different values for the DIST field.
This code is meant to add the "DIST" field to a feature class and fill it in based on the conditions in the UpdateCursor.

```
#Import arcpy and standard library modules 
import arcpy, sys, os

# Get feature class from argument
zoneArcSelect = sys.argv[1]

# Add DIST field to input feature class
arcpy.AddField_management(zoneArcSelect, "DIST", "SHORT")

#get rows using update cursor and conflict selection
rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(zoneArcSelect,"(LZONE = 'O-L' AND RZONE = 'M-1') OR (RZONE = 'O-L' AND LZONE = 'M-1')")

# calculate value for DIST and update row
for row in rows:
  row.DIST = 100
  rows.updateRow(row)

#get rows using update cursor and conflict selection
rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(zoneArcSelect,"(LZONE = 'M-1' AND RZONE = 'RPC') OR (RZONE = 'M-1' AND LZONE = 'RPC')")

# calculate value for DIST and update row
for row in rows:
  row.DIST = 200
  rows.updateRow(row)

#get rows using update cursor and conflict selection
rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(zoneArcSelect,"(LZONE = 'M-1' AND RZONE = 'RM-1') OR (RZONE = 'M-1' AND LZONE = 'RM-1')")

# calculate value for DIST and update row
for row in rows:
  row.DIST = 200
  rows.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Please follow the formatting [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to ask a question.

Comment: What is the error it generates? Are you using Arc 10.1 or later?

Comment: it is a syntax error. version 10.3 i believe

Answer (score 0):

It was my own fault not the codes that when I used the addField tool in modeler I didn't call them LZONE and RZONE. So that didn't match the code which caused the problem.